# PostgreSQL join json columns

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to write sql query to perform this task - combine all plans.features into one (if amount_images is present in both columns they should sum up, if one feature is present in one plan but not in other it should exist in output, if in one feature is marked as false and in other as true it should be true in output). Maybe that's too complicated but I would like to know the answer, here are the migrations

```
create table plans (
   id serial unique primary key not null,
   is_init boolean not null,
   price int not null,
   plan_name varchar not null,
   plan_description varchar not null,
   features jsonb not null,
   is_deprecated boolean not null default false,
   created_at timestamp with time zone not null default now()
);

create table payments(
    id varchar unique primary key,

    session_id varchar null,
    payment_intent_id varchar null,

    amount_paid bigint null,
    promocode_id varchar null,

    email varchar null,

    plan_id int not null references plans(id),
    version_id varchar null references versions(id),

    created_at timestamp with time zone not null,
    paid_at timestamp with time zone null
);
```

Here is query that I use to get features for specific version, but I have no idea what to do next, thanks

```
SELECT json_agg(plans.features) 
FROM payments 
  INNER JOIN plans ON payments.plan_id = plans.id 
WHERE payments.version_id='1' 
  AND payments.paid_at is not null
```

Example plans

```
INSERT INTO plans (is_init, price, plan_name, plan_description, features) VALUES (
    true, 1300, 'test', 'yeeeeeeah',
    '{
        "amount_images": 100,
        "upscale_limit": 0,
        "help": false
    }'
);

INSERT INTO plans (is_init, price, plan_name, plan_description, features) VALUES (
    true, 1300, 'test2', 'yeeeeeeah2',
    '{
        "amount_images": 10,
        "upscale_limit": 500,
        "help": true
    }'
);
```

Comment: To me this taks sounds weird. You have chosen a document model approach for storing features. This is an approach we choose when we want it easy for our apps to store and read the whole JSON tree and know that we probably won't query things that are inside the object. But this is exactly what you are trying to do here. And not only do you want to lookup a field in the JSON, but you want to aggregate the data. I'd say: If you want to do this, then you have chosen the wrong data model. Change this into a relational model where SQL helps you with querying and aggregating the data.

Comment: I completely agree with Thorsten here. However, it's also unclear to me what the output is you are after. Can you please [edit] your question and add the desired result?